# Place 2 divs next to each other with transform skew

Tags: html, css, transform, skew

I have a question:

I have two divs that are transformed with skew next to each other.  I want to attach them to each other. In my code, there is some padding between them. When I remove that padding, the transform is gone.

Can you help me out?

P.S. As you can see, I use bootstrap for my website.

Below is the link:

http://www.bootply.com/iA4MZwMyre

Here is my code :

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

    .col-xs-6 { padding: 0; }
  
    .skewLeft {     
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 1% 2%;
    }

    .skewLeft:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; right: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background: #f7de1d;
        -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
        -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
        transform-origin: 100% 0;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
        -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
        transform: skewX(-10deg);
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .skewRight { 
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 1% 2%;
    }

    .skewRight:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        background: #83d0f5;
        -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
        -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
        transform-origin: 100% 0;
        -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
        -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
        transform: skewX(-10deg);
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-6 skewLeft">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 skewRight">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's necro this :)

Just add a negative left margin to .skew-right. It worked with -23px for me, but you will probably need % or other relative unit.